# Tomcat DLL already loaded in another classloader

Tags: java, java-native-interface, tomcat7

I have a DLL that provides access to Window's LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary (to get around Java not being able to unload it). I need this DLL to persist between each webapp as it cannot be loaded twice.

I've followed these steps:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat

and placed a singleton class (as a jar) with the `static { System.loadLibrary() }` call under ${TOMCAT}/lib. When my Tomcat webapp accesses this Singleton, it still throws the error

`UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library ${TOMCAT}\lib\Native.dll already loaded in another classloader`

Is this wrong in thinking that Tomcat's common classloader is loading this class, instantiating it (as per: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) and then passing the reference to the webapp thus bypassing the webapp classloader?

Is there a way to tell Tomcat to instantiate my singleton (forcing the common classloader to do it) and then provide that instance to satisfy my webapp's dependency?

Any discussion much appreciated.

Comment: If you try to create the `$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib` as in the link mentions and place the dll there do you also get the same problem?Also your class has only the static initializer, right?

Comment: So in that link they describe the shared/lib for Tomcat6 and below. Currently, in Tomcat7, this has just simply moved to $CATALINA_HOME/lib. In the config you can see the common.loader property includes this. And no, the class has the single access function instance(), as well as the define JNI native functions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to unload dll:

http://www.codethesis.com/blog/unload-java-jni-dll

([web archive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20150518033642/http://www.codethesis.com/blog/unload-java-jni-dll))

I tried it with my web application running on Tomcat, and it works!

Briefly, I call System.loadLibrary from the class which is loaded by my custom class loader using reflection. This class is then removed by garbage collector.

Comment: this link is dead. Would you mind sharing your solution here or on another link?

Comment: @JomutechByte See https://web.archive.org/web/20150518033642/http://www.codethesis.com/blog/unload-java-jni-dll